# WebAudio doesn't play in some Edge-Installations

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, web-audio-api

I'm having some problems with WebAudio in Edge. I noticed this while testing my own app but it also happens with other Websites that use WebAudio like http://webaudioplayground.appspot.com/

When I try to play a sound no output is created. For example, an `AudioBufferSourceNode` that is connected with `AudioContext#destination` doesn't play anything when `AudioBufferSourceNode#start()` is called. Although the source-file is loaded and set into the node's Buffer, as I can see in the debugger.

But it doesn't matter if the source is a file or an oscillator.

The Problem doesn't appear on all Edge-installations,  it doesn't work on one notebook while the same code is running perfectly on another notebook.

I don't see any Error-Messages on the console…

Chrome and Firefox are working fine on all machines.

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug with Microsoft?  If the same code works with Chrome and Firefox on the same machines, it seems a pretty good indication that Edge is buggy somehow.

Comment: Maybe I have to do that, but I doubt that they would react… In fact there are several complaints about Edge not playing any audio at answers.microsoft.com but they are pretty fuzzy and non of the solutions suggested there worked for me. They don't talk about code there...

Comment: Doesn't Microsoft have a "real" bug tracker like crbugs.com for Chrome and bugzilla.mozilla.org for Firefox?  I assume answers.microsoft.com is community forum that may or may not get bugs assigned to the actual edge/webaudio team.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17608023/ seems to be the "real" bugtracker and this also seems to be the solution for my Problem. Except that in my case I'm using another wireles Headset. If I switch to monitor-Speakers WebAudio runs fine. So this is a bug in Edge